# Is there a .NET 4.0 offline install?

Tags: installation, .net, .net-4.0

I'm trying to install .NET 4.0 on some VMs using dotNetFx40_Full_setup.exe and am getting error 0x800C0005. The issue likely involves the firewall/proxy/security configuration. Rather than dealing with that, does Microsoft have an offline install available yet? I've searched but not found one.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This looks like the [right link](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?displaylang=en&FamilyID=0a391abd-25c1-4fc0-919f-b21f31ab88b7) to me.

Answer (score 2):

A page containing downloads for all the .NET offline installers can be found at http://www.microsoft.com/net/download. It includes downloads for the full framework, client profile, x86, x64 and IA-64.